# localStorage getItem is returning null

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having some trouble retrieving values from localStorage after login. The problem is here

`getOrgId(){
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('orgId')) //Give null
    return localStorage.getItem('orgId')
  }`

It give value null but when I reload page, I get value.

**Auth.Service**

```
public loginUser(userData: LoginRequest): Observable<LoginResponse> {
  console.log(userData.password)
    return this.http.post<LoginResponse>("api/auth/login", userData,httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap( // Log the result or error
          data => {
            if (data.status['message'] === 'Success.') {
              const loginData = {role: data.role, user: data.user, token: data.token,orgId:data.orgId,email:data.email,orgName:data.orgName};
              localStorage.setItem('loginData', JSON.stringify(loginData));
              localStorage.setItem('loginUserId', userData.userId);
              localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(loginData.token));
              localStorage.setItem('orgId', JSON.stringify(loginData.orgId));
              localStorage.setItem('email', JSON.stringify(loginData.email));
              localStorage.setItem('orgName',JSON.stringify(loginData.orgName));
              localStorage.setItem('role', JSON.stringify(loginData.role));
              console.log("logindata:" +loginData.orgId); //Give Value
              console.log(this.isLoggedIn());
              this.login.next(this.isLoggedIn());
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
            } else {
              localStorage.removeItem('loginData');
              localStorage.removeItem('loginUserId');
              localStorage.removeItem('token');
              localStorage.removeItem('orgId');
              localStorage.removeItem('orgName');
              this.login.next(this.isLoggedIn());
            }
          },
          error => {
            localStorage.removeItem('loginData');
            localStorage.removeItem('loginUserId');
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            localStorage.removeItem('orgId');
            localStorage.removeItem('orgName');
            this.login.next(this.isLoggedIn());
            console.log(error);
          }
        )
      );
  }

getOrgId(){
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('orgId')) //Give null
    return localStorage.getItem('orgId')
  }
```

Comment: When you trying to get, Is orgId is available in localStorage. Is it properly set there. Are you trying to get it  before it is set. Please check once.

Comment: Yes.. Is available.. i've add `console.log("logindata:" +loginData.orgId); ` bellow `localStorage.setItem`. And it give value

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this answer would help you or not, bcs I'm struggling in angular too for this several months.

I see you need to collect a value from ur localStorage with a function. Maybe my code will help u :/

|| I'm using java for webservice, btw ||

**Authentication.service.ts**

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
return this.http.post < any > (this.a.SERVER_URL + '/system/auth/newLogin', { // /authentication/login
// return this.http.post < any > (this.a.SERVER_URL + '/authentication/login', {
    username: username,
    password: password
  })
  .map(user => {
    // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
    console.log(user);
    if (user && user.d) {
    // if (user && user.token) {
      // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('username', username);
      localStorage.setItem('entitas_id', user.d.entitas_id);
      localStorage.setItem('role_id', user.d.role_id);
      localStorage.setItem('token', user.d.token);
      localStorage.setItem('active', user.d.active);
      localStorage.setItem('jabatan_id', user.d.jabatan_id);
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    } else {
      // Gagal Login
      this.options.message = user.m;
      notify(this.options, 'error', 3000);
    }

    return user;
  });
```

}

**Some file that contain a function that I need to collect value from localStorage**

```
BaruChanged(e){
    console.log(e)
    const jabatan = localStorage.getItem('jabatan_id');
    const entitas_id = localStorage.getItem('entitas_id');
    const username = localStorage.getItem('username').toString().toUpperCase();
    this.role.username=username;
    this.role.entitas_id = entitas_id;
    this.role.jabatan = jabatan;

  }
```

I'm saving the localStorage.getItem('jabatan_id') into some const. That's what I want to show you about :))

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But it not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you might calling the **getOrgId()** function in ngOninit() or in component Constructor thats why it gives null because before setting the value in local sotrage you are calling the getOrgId() function.

Just write an console in both function **getOrgId()** & **loginUser()** an check which one is prints first.